# How to forward request to route name

Tags: symfony

```
$controller->forward(...)
```

requires a string in form or `MyBundle:Controller:action`, but I only have route name.

How to forward request to route name?

Comment: željko, I think you should accept Josh'es answer because it seems to do exactly what you've asked. I had the same problem as you did, and it solved it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

this question is old but for the sake of documentation and for all the googlers out there here is one way of doing it.

```
class Mycontroller extends Controller {
  public function indexAction(){
        $response = $this->forward($this->routeToControllerName('ROUTE_NAME_HERE'));
  }

  private function routeToControllerName($routename) {
    $routes = $this->get('router')->getRouteCollection();
    return $routes->get($routename)->getDefaults()['_controller'];
  }

}
```

Comment: There is a typo: the parameter is named `routname`, but you want to get `routename`.

Comment: This is old, but it might save someone some headache. If you forward to another controller action, app.request.attributes.get("_route") no longer works in 3.4. Redirect is better when possible as you're maintaining a normal flow.

Answer (score 5):

Redirect to route name 'homepage':

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class TaskController extends AbstractController
{

   public function goHome()
   {
      return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Forward** to controller.

**Redirect** to a page (by route)

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#redirecting

Comment: I know that but I really need forward to route name

Answer (score 0):

Beware of

```
router->getRouteCollection()
```

It is suggested in the accepted answer, but using this method will regenerate the Routing cache on each request, making apps very slow.

```
https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/6710
```